# check on uniqid for session

Tags: php, session, cookies, unique-id

For user authentication, my client redirects to server and gets user data and I store it into php native session on client side. In this process Server redirects back on same requested url so if there is no data in response there will not be any session on client side and my script will end up in redirect loop as there is a check to redirect to server only if session not found.

Now to avoid such case, I am creating a random session after first flow using uniqid('prefix_') function. But if someone refreshes the page, request should again go to server for authentication.

For that I am checking for session cookie value. If cookie has my given prefix (given in uniqid) then it is not a valid session and redirect to server. I want to know how reliable this option is? Do I have any other solution?

Update : 
Here how my validSession function looks like :

`public function validSession() {

        if ($sessionCookie !== null && substr($sessionCookie,0,7) !== 'prefix_')

            return true;

        return false;

    }`

So if session cookie contains prefix which was used to create random session in case of no data from server, this function will return me false and I will decide to redirect to server for user session.

Comment: too much confusing without code.. please add code to your question..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a flow control problem.  Just don't redirect back if the login fails.

```
@session_start();
$user = Auth::login($username, $pwd);
if (!empty($user))
{
  $_SESSION['auth_user'] = $user;
  session_write_close();
  header('Location: '.$_REQUEST['next']);
}
else
{
  header('Location: '.Auth::STANDARD_LOGIN_URL);
}
```

This example uses a psuedo Auth class, with a static login method (returns a user or false/null on failure), and a constant which defines where to go to log in.

Comment: Suppressing potential errors caused by `session_start()` such as not being able to set the session cookies are a great way to run into hard-to-debug problems later.

Comment: Usually there's no need to call `session_write_close()` - it's done automatically. You only need it if the script is going to do some time-consuming stuff after being finished with accessing the session.

Comment: I can buy that argument -- however the #1 issue in code is that you don't easily know whether or not the session has been started if you've got a pile of code... and a proper management setup would complicate my simplified demo greatly.  This is one of the reasons my standard classes have abstraction for all session management.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Totally disagree with the session_write_close argument, if you're doing an immediate redirection -- that is ABSOLUTELY the most important time to call session_write_close.  Otherwise, it can get lost as the PHP lifecycle shuts down on the client's reset new URL call for the redirection.

Comment: Why not simply `exit()` after sending the header? Besides that, the browser won't process the redirect until everything has been received - and in this case the script has terminated and thus closed the session.

Comment: In my experience, the browser can/will process the header before the script has terminated.  The 'exit;' call should mostly work, but I've definitely seen issues with that in the past too.  In fact, I just cleaned up some 2 year old comments in some code cursing this exact issue with some rather colorful expletives.

Comment: @John what if there is no standard login URL? let's say some widget which will display user data if session exists otherwise simply shows login form.

Comment: @CM - Ok, then the flow control changes again.  I was addressing the Op's problem of being stuck in a redirect loop.  Looks like he intercepts whether a user is logged in, redirects to a login page if he isn't, then was redirecting back, even in the case of a failed login.  In your example, you wouldn't do the redirects... heck, you'd probably just start the session up and do a simple condition based off of that.  From there, you'd write data based on that condition.

Comment: @John I am an OP :) and my case is same ..I need to check from same page if session exists don't redirect else do a redirect to server. and tht's why problem of redirect loop comes.

Comment: lol.  Sorry.  Redirect to server?  Is this question more about bridging authentication with a 3rd party auth management solution (like OpenID)?

Comment: Ok, the 3rd party auth gives you a callback, correct?  This means that you know whether or not you're in one of the following contexts:  Authed, Failed Auth, No Auth.  For Authed, you display your content.  For No Auth (assuming it is mandatory), you redirect to the auth server.  For Failed Auth, you dump a message to the screen asking them to try again (and not show any 'actual' content).  Although I'm not sure I understand what you're doing... because a failed auth should fail at the auth server and be taken care of there.

Comment: well in my case, I don't have these 3 options available although there are some parameters I am getting in response so I will check on it ..meanwhile can you tell me if approach which I have mentioned in my question is reliable in terms of security ?